# Where should I place the process that don't have relation to UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In case I want to load data to display to UI (e.g.Timeline of Twitter), I place the process of API call to viewDidLoad.
however, I couldn't find the place similar to viewDidLoad in Apple Tutorials.

Where should I place the process that don't have relation to UI?

Comment: How do you mean? what tutorials? what are you trying to do?

Comment: tutorials is [this](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/tutorials)

Comment: Is your question does viewDidLoad exist in SwiftUI and is there an equivalent?

Comment: tutorial explain how to configure UI Components using SwiftUI, but I couldn't find where should I place other process.

I found `onAppear`, but it is require to return value(I couldn't find any information to `_ModifiedContent<ContentView, _AppearanceActionModifier>`)

Comment: when I create new xcodeproj, `viewDidLoad` weren't exist

Comment: Is UIKit replaceable by SwiftUI?
What in SwiftUI Framework equivalent to ViewController?

Comment: A SwiftUI 'file' is just a view, its not a view controller. So you can add the SwiftUI view to the view controller and then you have access to VC life cycle events just as view did load, then you should be able to use bindings to bind the data results back into the view

Comment: OK.
Swift UI is equivalent to Storyboard only and To develop working App, I have to create ViewController on manually.
that correct?

or is there way to develop without ViewController?

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI gives us same to UIKit’s viewDidAppear() and viewDidDisappear() methods but their name is little bit different which are onAppear() and onDisappear().

```
struct DetailView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
            }.onAppear {
// enter viewDidAppear() code here
        }
    }
}
```